# anyway to specify a target <router-outlet> for a route

Tags: angular

My page is setup with a router-outlet.  There is one of these that serves all the components in a sidebar navigation and I keep having to go to the same component to add more routes.

I would like to be able to let components define the routes so each component can encapsulate this information based on their own template.

The problem I've run into is that if I specify routes at the component level they are dependent on me adding an additional router-outlet because they are seen as child routes.  I'd like to know if there is a configuration option to specify which router-outlet any given route should target if available.

thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

only I know is expend child routes to other component like:
first
{path：‘/project/...‘, component：second}
... means expend route to second component

second set up by this
{path ： ‘/‘........useAsdefault ：true(this is very important )

Answer (score 0):

You could use auxiliary routes and named router-outlets. But auxiliary routes have some issues https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4945.
You can't activate them using a `<router-link>` only by `_router.navigateByUrl('/mainroute(auxroute)');